# Understanding floating point representation errors; what's wrong with my thinking?

Tags: floating-point, floating-accuracy

I'm having some trouble understanding why some figures can't be represented with floating point number.

As we know, a normal float would have sign bit, exponent, and mantissa. Why can't, for example, 0.1 be represented accurately in this system; the way I think of it would be that you put 10 (1010 in bin) to mantissa and -2 to the exponent. As far as I know, both numbers can be accurately represented in the mantissa and exponent. So why can't we represent 0.1 accurately?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your exponent is decimal (i.e. it represents 10^X), you can precisely represent 0.1 -- however, most floating point formats use binary exponents (i.e. they represent 2^X). Since there are no integers `X` and `Y` such that `Y * (2 ^ X) = 0.1`, you cannot precisely represent 0.1 in most floating point formats.

Some languages have types with both exponents. In C#, for example, there is a data type aptly named `decimal` which is a floating point format with a decimal exponent so it will support storing a number like 0.1, although it has other uncommon properties: The `decimal` type can distinguish between `0.1` and `0.10`, and it is always true that `x + 1 != x` for all values of `x`.

For most common purposes, though, C# also has the `float` and `double` floating point types that cannot precisely store 0.1 because they use a binary exponent (as defined in IEEE-754). The binary floating point types use less storage, are faster because they are easier to implement, and have more operations defined on them. In general `decimal` is only used for financial values where the exact representation of all decimal values is important and the storage, speed, and range of operations are not.

Answer (score 3):

You must start reading [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Check out :

- [Floating-Point Number Tutorial](http://www.cs.utah.edu/~zachary/isp/applets/FP/FP.html)
- [Tutorial: Floating-Point Binary](http://kipirvine.com/asm/workbook/floating_tut.htm)

Answer (score 3):

Each floating-point number in the IEEE 754 standard is, in effect, some integer multiplied by some integer power of two. E.g., 3 is represented by 3 * 2<sup>0</sup>, 96 is represented by 3 * 2<sup>3</sup>, and 3/16 is represented by 3 * 2<sup>-4</sup>.

There are no integers x and y such that .1 = x * 2<sup>y</sup>, therefore .1 cannot be exactly represented by a floating-point number. Proof: If .1 = x * 2<sup>y</sup>, then 10x = 2<sup>-y</sup>. 2<sup>-y</sup> is clearly positive, so x is positive. It is also an integer, so 10x is divisible by 10, so it is divisible by 5. Therefore 2<sup>-y</sup> is a power of two that is divisible by 5, which is clearly impossible.

Answer (score 1):

That would be 10 × 2<sup>-1</sup> = 5, not 0.1.

Generally, it's like representing one-third in base ten: it's just not possible with a finite number of digits.

By the way, 10<sub>10</sub> = 1010<sub>2</sub> ≠ 1100<sub>2</sub>.

Answer (score 0):

You're thinking about 1* 10^-1, which works for a [decimal floating number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_floating_point) representation, such as decimal in C#. The normal floating point (such as float, double) uses binary representation, i.e. in powers of 2

Normally, binary is used because they can be more efficiently arranged in bits. Decimal is normally used when absolute decimal precision is required, for example when counting money.