# Strategy for connecting 180 V's via edges (current process frozen)

Tags: java, api, graph-databases, orientdb

Well I had my Java process running over night. First of all, that is what I already have.

I have basically:

```
80 mio entries (stuff Person have written) and
50 mio entries of Persons
```

Now I have a CSV file that is connecting both via ID's.

My first idea on the Java implementation was by 200 entries/sec. (noTx)

While my latest is ~2000/sec. (Tx)

But now I'm looking on the current state of the system. And I still see CPU and RAM changing and process is still running. But when I look onto the IO values. It's just reading.

So I was thinking that maybe the lines just contain ID's that are not in the database. Maybe! But I have a syso that shows me every 10,000 lines the current state. And it's not coming up anymore. So this cannot be.

Btw I'm at line 16.777.000 right now. And it's somehow frozen I would say. It's working really hardcore but doing nothing =/

Btw2 I:

```
use Transactions every 100 lines
STORAGE_KEEP_OPEN=true
ENVIRONMENT_CONCURRENT=false
OIntentMassiveInsert=true
setUsingLog=false
```

You can find the log here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/orient-database/Whedj893mIY

Comment: 2^24 is 16,777,216. Some sort of arbitrary limit perhaps?

Comment: Ohh that's a good point, that could be the reason, because I'm using a float. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12596695/why-does-a-float-variable-stop-incrementing-at-16777216-in-c I try to disable the float variable and syso lines. Let's see.

Comment: Great not it runs. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to care about the magic size **2^24 is 16,777,216** as seen in the comments.